# pointwise convergence contested

Tags: convergence-divergence

[image]

From the joint image, how does $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$?

For instance, I can't find an integer $A$ such that $n>A \Longrightarrow |f_n(x)|\le 1/2, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Your $A$ can not be found (for ech $n$ there will always be an $x$ such that $f_n(x)=1$). And that's ok because $f_n$ converges only _pointwise_ to zero but not uniformly.

Comment: In pointwise convergence, you search an $A$ for each $x$ (they can be different!), not an $A$ for all $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n>x$, we have $f_n(x)=1_{[n,n+1]}(x)=0$. So for any $x$, as $n \to \infty$, $f_n(x) \to 0$.